# Model not passed from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problem passing a model from a controller to a view. I get an error inside the view saying that the model is null. Can anyone see what I have done wrong, and how should I do so the model gets passed to the view correctly?

This is a part of the method in the controller:

```cs
var msg2 = new ErrorViewModel { Message = "Could not find the report", Test = "1" };
return View("~/Shared/Error.cshtml", msg2);
```

This is a part of the view:

```
@model QbimEmbeddedV2.Models.ViewModels.ErrorViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<body>

    @Model.Message
    @Model.Test

    <hgroup class="p-25">
        <h1>Error.</h1>
        @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Message))
        {
            <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

        }
        else
        {
            <h2>@Model.Message</h2>
        }
        <h2><a href="/">Home</a></h2>
    </hgroup>

</body>
```

I get the error on the @Model.Message row

I want @Model.Message to be displayed properly

The error message I get is:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious: when you place a breakpoint somewhere in that action and debug, the breakpoint is hit? Error.cshtml, in that location, is also used by the HandleErrorAttribute, which is added by default in pre-Core MVC projects.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes it's hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from running the below code is: [Output of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D70q7.png)

### Controller.

```
var Model = new ErrorViewModel { Message = "Error Occured for the 
Controller",Test="1"};
return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml",Model);
```

### View

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Error";
 }

<h2>Error</h2>

@Model.Message
@Model.Test


@if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Message))
{
    <h1>Error was Occured</h1>
} 
else
{
    <h1>@Model.Message</h1>
}
```

I hope this Code might help you.